# Load a TableViewController on an animated UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

Is it possible to load a `UITableViewController` on a `UIView`?

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PV8ARcZfAxo) in animating a `UIView`, but I want it to load a `UITableViewController`. The reason why I need to laod a `UITableViewController` is that i have 2 sets of buttons that will use the `UIView` but will display different types of tables with different type of icons. I am trying to recycle the `UIViewController` that I made it work using a popover menu when a button is clicked but I feel like a sliding `UIView` will give a better user experience.

Anyway, I'm basically trying to load a `UITableViewController` onto that `UIView`. Not sure if it's the right way, if not, is it better to just load a `UITableView` instead? I just feel like it'll have more code on one file and will be confusing when maintaining it specially if there are 2 different types of data or rows that needs to be loaded.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Just load the table view instead. It won't be all that much new code - and you are using `#pragma mark -`, right?

Comment: That is true. My worry is that, let's say I ahve two buttons that will show different data on the tableview. the first button requires 2 icons on the CustomTableCell which we will call FightTableCell. While the other one will not have any but needs a checkbox which is FighterTableCell. How do I switch between the two, I use storyboards btw, I'm sure you can do that on IB, not really sure about storyboards?

Comment: @Gdubs Just set a different source of data for your table view when the toggle button is pressed. For example, you are probably populating your table view from an array. When your toggle button is pressed, you can change the data in that array and call `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: I know what you're talking about, but what I mean is, you know how you drag and drop objects eg. label, imageview, etc on to the "prototype cell" and then drag those to connect to the objects on your custom uitablecell class? They basically have different objects.