# Two uitable into one uiview

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

So this is related to this question I asked not too long ago and I'm trying to figure out if the solution I came up with is feasible, I would try it but I'm not really sure how to start

[Load a TableViewController on an animated UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292208/load-a-tableviewcontroller-on-an-animated-uiview)

So what I wanted to do is to have two different results when a animated uiview pops up.

1. I have two buttons. One button will have a uitable that shows a label and 3 icons, while the other will show one label and a different icon.
2. I'm using storyboards (since that's the only way I know how to do it) to connect a "Custom UitableCell" to the table.
3. I dragged two uitableviews and force them to be hidden from the view when viewdidload happens. So I place a prototype cell on each uitableview specific to what objects I need displayed when it gets loaded.
4. Now I add the uitabledelegate and datasource on the viewcontroller file.

Now my issue is, if I do this on the viewcontroller, can it only communicate to one uitable and not two? (eg. didselectrow, numberofrowsinsection, cellforrowatindexpath, etc) Or can I do and "if else" to figure out which uitable view it is communicating (or loading info) with?

[This is the tutorial I followed for th uiview animation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PV8ARcZfAxo)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your view controller can be the data source and delegate of two uitableview or more.

Make your two UITableView properties of the view controller. Then in your delegate and data source methods, you can check the tableView parameter passed in each method, for example:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    if (tableView == self.firstTableView) {
        return 1; //for the firstTableView
    } else {
        return 2; //this will be for the secondTableView
    }
}
```

Do the same for your other data source and delegate methods.